# Making overloaded member access operator in C++ return a temporary

Tags: c++, iterator, dereference, value-categories

I want to write class similar to below, where `IteratorLike` can only be dereferenced to a new value, as the iterator provides a view different to the underlying structure that makes returning a simple reference unfeasible.

```
class IteratorLike
{
public:
    MyValue operator*() const { return MyValue(...); }
    auto operator->() const { return **this; } // This does not work generally due to member access semantics.
};
```

All in all, I just want `IteratorLike()->x` to *mean the same thing* as `(*IteratorLike()).x`.

One could simply overload `operator->()` in the `MyValue` class, but i want this to work in all cases.
Using a wrapper type that overloads `operator->()` seemed like a plausible solution, but this does not work when returning an rvalue.
In [the example on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/sk8M3_) is a working implementation of such a wrapper, including the undefined behaviour it causes due to the dangling reference.

### Is there a way to make this work?

If the wrapper could return a pointer to an prvalue, then the line `int &qa = MyIteratorLike()->x;` would in my understanding be caught by the compiler, but such a thing seems impossible.

Comment: To be clear, you want `int &qa = MyIteratorLike()->x;` to be an error, but `use_something(MyIteratorLike()->x);` to be allowed? [Adjusted godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/zU4KsS)

Comment: @Caleth Yeah, you understood my worries there correctly. Though to be clear, that is just one example where the expression `(*IteratorLike()).x` just naturally has correct semantics in the cases i looked at, while `->` just does not behave analogously. If this is not possible without twisting the language too much i accept defeat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to make this work?

No. Value category is a property of an expression, not of a type. "pointer to prvalue" is not a thing